# How push element to array from ajax - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, push

When I try push some element to array and display random element, browser return that array is not define. Where is problem?

```
var dir = "./images/radovi/";
var ext = ".png";
var slike = [];
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + ext + ")").each(function () {
            var ime_slike = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
            slike.push(dir + ime_slike + ext);
        });
    }
});
$('<img src="' + slike[Math.floor(Math.random() * slike.length)] + '">').appendTo('#radovi');
```

Comment: Try `slike[Math.floor(Math.random() * (slike.length-1))]`

Comment: I tried, again same thing. In console return this error "GET http://localhost/test/undefined 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is Asynchronous.  The code that populates your array is being called *after* the code that uses the array.  Move the code that creates the image into the success handler:

```
var dir = "./images/radovi/";
var ext = ".png";
var slike = [];
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + ext + ")").each(function () {
            var ime_slike = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
            slike.push(dir + ime_slike + ext);
        });
        if (slike.length) {
            $('<img src="' + slike[Math.floor(Math.random() * slike.length)] + '">').appendTo('#radovi');
        }
    }
});
```